# Using Wget i'm not able to the download of entire website

Tags: linux, wget

I want to download entire website but also resume the job if I want to kill it.
My problem is that when I run the command the second time it never enters in the subfolders created previously.
I tried the option `--mirror` and `--no-clobber` too but the same error happened
Now I'm using the command like this:

```
wget --recursive -l inf --no-clobber --page-requisites --no-parent --domains xxx https://xxx/
```

In particular this is an example of what I obtain:

```
--2021-01-09 15:46:11--  https://domain/subfolder/
Reusing existing connection to domain:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
domain/subfolder: Is a directory

Cannot write to ‘domain/subfolder’ (Success).
```

The second time I run it the command stops soon, skipping all the check of the files inside the directories.

Is there a solution to do some check inside folders already created by the previous `wget` job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guys today i figured it out, the problem was not an option of recursion or continuation, but the 301 response back. I still don't understand why it's followed the first time, but now everything works well. I can stop the job and resume and after checking every file wget will download something new or continue previously download.
As always happen someone had same problem and this is the link
https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-wget/2019-11/msg00036.html

If can help for someone the command i'm using now is
wget -r --mirror -N -l inf --no-parent -R --trust-server-names --content-disposition --continue --domains site https://site

As you can see and read on the past question the option that allow follow redirect is --trust-server-names. I then combined with --content-disposition and everything works fine.

Thanks all of you for the help

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the option `--timestamping` (`-N` in short), that retrieves only files newer than existing one.

For your reference, the command that I actually used sometimes is:

```bsh
wget -c -N -mirror -pc --convert-links -P ./mirror $SITE_URL
```

Comment: the resource on the website are not updated, they are never downloaded.

Comment: This is inside the output of wget:
Last-modified header missing -- time-stamps turned off
and nothing change it doesn't check if the file inside sub folder are fully downloaded

Comment: Have you used the `-c` flag too? It should skip files that are already downloaded and of the same size. Please try my proposed command in its integral part, replacing `$SITE_URL` with your desired website.

Comment: I tried just now i uset your parameters, i just wait it to download the first subfolders layer, then i killed it during a download of a big file. Starting again, same command, it terminate soon. It's because Is it because doesn't enter in the subfolder?

Comment: probably yes. But I do not understand: was that big file correctly downloaded?

Comment: No i killed it while downloading the big file

Comment: from the wget manual: `On the other side of the coin, while using -c, any file that's bigger on the server than locally will be considered an incomplete download and only "(length(remote) - length(local))" bytes will be downloaded and tacked onto the end of the local file. This behavior can be desirable in certain cases---for instance, you can use wget -c to download just the new portion that's been appended to a data collection or log file.` So I suppose that any incomplete file (local dimension lower than the server one), should be downloaded again with the flag `-c`.

Comment: i know that but it doesn't work. the option continue is related to file that was interrupted, but that file is inside the second layer of folder and it is not checked. The target website has more than 1 file, but it skip resume the operation due to that error.
thanks for the help btw